# Python Decorator class with arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, hook, metaprogramming, python-decorators

I have a simple Python class that I want to use to add named hooks to a program I am writing. I try to run the below code and I get the following output.

---

Code:

```
hooks = {}

class hook(object):
    def __init__(self, f, hook):
        if hook not in hooks:
            hooks[hook] = []

        hooks[hook].append({"module": f.__module__, "func": f})
        self.f = f

    def __call__(self, *args):
        f(*args)

@hook("test")
def testHook():
    print "hi"
```

---

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                       
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                    
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

How can I fix this? I am using Python 2.7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your decorator syntax:

```
@hook("test")
def testHook():
    # ...
```

translates to:

```
def testHook():
    # ...

testHook = hook("test")(testHook)
```

so it is given just *one* argument. You need to restructure your code to produce your class decorator as a *return value* of `hook()`.

The following would work:

```
def hook(hookname):
    class HookDecorator(object):
        def __init__(self, f):
            if hookname not in hooks:
                hooks[hookname] = []
    
            hooks[hook].append({"module": f.__module__, "func": f})
            self.f = f
    
        def __call__(self, *args):
            return self.f(*args)

    return HookDecorator
```

where the `__call__` uses `self.f`, not the global `f`, and returns whatever the decorated function produced. I'm assuming that `hooks` is a global dictionary somewhere.

There is little point in making this a class however; you use very little state. You could just as well use a wrapper *function* here:

```
from functools import wraps

hooks = {}

def hook(hookname):
    def decorator(f):
        if hookname not in hooks:
            hooks[hookname] = []
    
        hooks[hookname].append({"module": f.__module__, "func": f})

        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args):
            return f(*args)

        return wrapper

    return decorator
```